# Image upload (POST) from python

Tags: python, networking, http-post, urllib

I want to upload an image to **onlineocr.net** from python and use BeautifulSoup to extract the answer from the response
(target div id is 'MainContent_PanelOCRResult').

Code is attached here:

```
import requests as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.onlineocr.net/'

file = {'media': open('OCR.png', 'rb'),
        'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'}

response = req.post(link, files = file)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find_all('div', {'id':"MainContent_PanelOCRResult"} ))
```

The problem I'm currently facing is that the response I'm getting does not have the result. In fact is just the normal page without any file uploaded or ocr processing.

Do provide some help.

Thank you.

Comment: My response has code 200 when I run this, and the print output is an empty list

Comment: @naraghi Yes, that is the problem. Response 200 means the request was serviced.
The list that is Supposed to be printed should have the OCR result, but my code gives the empty list, meaning I did not get the correct result. That is the problem for which I asked to question to solve.
If you wnat to see what the response html is, you can add the line at the end `print(soup)`